# In case of multiple GPUs which one does actual rendering to all the monitors?

Tags: gpu, multi-gpu

Can anyone explain or point to an explanation (or at least to some clues) of how rendering in multi-gpu/multi-monitors setup work?

For example I got 5 NVIDIA Quadro 4000 video cards installed and 9 displays connected to them. The displays are not grouped whatsoever. Just arranged in Windows 7 that the total resolution is 4098x2304. The cards are not connected with SLI either.

I got a Flash app which sees a 4096x2304 window as a single Stage3d context (using dx9) and can work with this quite unusual setup as though it was just a huge display with only one video card.

How does the rendering work internally? What video cards are actually doing? Do they share resources? Who renders all the stuff? Why do I get 29.9 fps doing mostly nothing in the app?

Thank you.

Comment: 9 displays?!  ...jeezus.  I'd love to see a picture of that setup.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for DX, but for OpenGL I've collected this information here: http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html

In short, on Windows with new nVidia drivers one GPU (typically the first) renders everything and the others get the content blitted. If you enable SLI Mosaic Mode, the GL commands are sent to all GPUs, giving you scalability for the fill rate.

Comment: I would assume in a similar fashion. Iirc D3D has an API for selecting the device.